# Pod issue -: Nanaimo::Reader::ParseError - [!] Array missing ',' in between objects

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

I'm getting issue during install pod in react-native project

**Nanaimo::Reader::ParseError - [!] Array missing ',' in between objects**
please help me if anyone have idea about that.

[image]

Comment: It tells you the error. You have a bad xcodeproj file. It shows you the bad line.

Comment: Thanks,
Can you let me know what should I do for that?

Comment: Edit the project's _project.pbxproj_ in a text editor and figure out what the issue is. — By the way, do not attempt to run `pod install` when Xcode is running! Quit Xcode first.

Comment: @matt I try but not working.
thanks 
I have also try 
gem install nanaimo:0.2.2
but getting error

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.


https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6129

Comment: Use sudo @AnilKumarPatil

Comment: Using VSCode and checking error syntax in the project's `project.pbxproj`.

Answer (score 1):

The error is basically telling that you have a syntax mistake in the file. In my case while using "React Native Upgrade Guide" I was pasting the changed line and forgot to add a comma.
**Make sure you have no trailing commas and you are closing the lines with semicolons!**

P.S. The line of code which was pointed at in the terminal wasn't the exact line where the mistake was made in my case but the comma was missing 3-4 lines before so be careful, it might be misleading...

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there was an interruption during initial pod install (cloning repository using lfs).

Or you may have copy and pasted the source code without proper cloning procedure.

You can wipe clean pods by:

```
rm -rf ~/.cocoapods
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
```

Then wipe any generated files inside project root by:

```
git clean -dfx
```

And, after all that, you can try `pod install --repo-update` again inside the iOS folder.

Comment: I don't prefer use `git clean -dfx`, it will remove changes in your folder.