# Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set

Tags: flutter, macos, cocoapods, podfile

[macos version and terminal photo here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTn30.png) `RubyGems : 3.5.4 Host : macOS 14.3.1 (23D60) Xcode : 15.0 (15A240d) Git : git version 2.39.3 (Apple Git-145) Ruby lib dir : /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.3.0/lib Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/ ### Plugins cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.5 cocoapods-plugins : 1.0.0 cocoapods-search : 1.0.1 cocoapods-trunk : 1.6.0 cocoapods-try : 1.2.0 ### Podfile ruby # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project # platform :ios, '11.0' # CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency. ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true' project 'Runner', { 'Debug' => :debug, 'Profile' => :release, 'Release' => :release, } def flutter_root generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__) unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first" end File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line| matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/) return matches[1].strip if matches end raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get" end require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root) flutter_ios_podfile_setup target 'Runner' do use_frameworks! use_modular_headers! flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__)) end post_install do |installer| installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target| flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target) end end ### Error Nanaimo::Reader::ParseError - [!] Invalid character ";" in unquoted string # ------------------------------------------- # "@executable_path/Frameworks", # ); 518> MARKETING_VERSION = ; ^ # PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = com.fnsdata.hattatfaturaportal; # PRODUCT_NAME = "$(TARGET_NAME)"; # ------------------------------------------- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/nanaimo-0.3.0/lib/nanaimo/reader.rb:284:in raise_parser_error' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/nanaimo-0.3.0/lib/nanaimo/reader.rb:150:in parse_string' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/nanaimo-0.3.0/lib/nanaimo/reader.rb:140:in parse_object' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/nanaimo-0.3.0/lib/nanaimo/reader.rb:193:in parse_dictionary' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/nanaimo-0.3.0/lib/nanaimo/reader.rb:132:in parse_object' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/nanaimo-0.3.0/lib/nanaimo/reader.rb:193:in parse_dictionary' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/nanaimo-0.3.0/lib/nanaimo/reader.rb:132:in parse_object' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/nanaimo-0.3.0/lib/nanaimo/reader.rb:193:in parse_dictionary' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/nanaimo-0.3.0/lib/nanaimo/reader.rb:132:in parse_object' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/nanaimo-0.3.0/lib/nanaimo/reader.rb:193:in parse_dictionary' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/nanaimo-0.3.0/lib/nanaimo/reader.rb:132:in parse_object' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/nanaimo-0.3.0/lib/nanaimo/reader.rb:107:in parse!' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/xcodeproj-1.24.0/lib/xcodeproj/plist.rb:27:in read_from_path' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/xcodeproj-1.24.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:211:in initialize_from_file' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/xcodeproj-1.24.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:113:in open' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1194:in block (2 levels) in inspect_targets_to_integrate' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1193:in each' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1193:in block in inspect_targets_to_integrate' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in section' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1188:in inspect_targets_to_integrate' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:107:in analyze' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:422:in analyze' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:244:in block in resolve_dependencies' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in section' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243:in resolve_dependencies' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:162:in install!' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in run' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in run' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in run' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/bin/pod:55:in <top (required)>' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/bin/pod:25:in load' /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/bin/pod:25:in <main>' ――― TEMPLATE END ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― [!] Oh no, an error occurred. Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=%5B%21%5D+Invalid+character+%22%3B%22+in+unquoted+string%0A+++%23++-------------------------------------------%0A+++%23++%09%09%09%09%09%22%40executable_path%2FFrameworks%22%2C%0A+++%23++%09%09%09%09%29%3B%0A518%3E++%09%09%09%09MARKETING_VERSION+%3D+%3B%0A++++++%09%09%09%09++++++++++++++++++++%5E%0A+++%23++%09%09%09%09PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER+%3D+com.fnsdata.hattatfaturaportal%3B%0A+++%23++%09%09%09%09PRODUCT_NAME+%3D+%22%24%28TARGET_NAME%29%22%3B%0A+++%23++-------------------------------------------%0A&type=Issues If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md Don't forget to anonymize any private data! Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods... Searching for inspections failed: undefined method map' for nil hattat@192 ios %` 
I tried things like deleting and restoring the pod but it didn't work.

I deleted the pod, restored it, updated it and it still didn't work. I downloaded the old xcode version and it didn't work, I downloaded the latest xcode version and it didn't work. I don't know what to do anymore can you help me? All codes and images are available above

Comment: This link may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/72855456/4373661

Comment: I tried but the error is still the same didn't work